# Create custom hibernate Validator based on existing Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I would like to create a custom constraint `@LengthIfNotBlank(min=,max=)` based on Hibernates `@Length` constraint:

```
@Target( { METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = LengthIfNotBlankValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface LengthIfNotBlank {
    String message() default "{com.mycompany.LengthIfNotBlank}";
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    int max() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    int min() default 0;
}

public class LengthIfNotBlankValidator extends LengthValidator {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return StringUtils.isBlank(value) || super.isValid(value, constraintValidatorContext);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
[java] javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to initialize com.example.constraints.LengthIfNotBlankValidator
[java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy32 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length
```

**UPDATE**

Still getting this exception :-(

```
public class LengthIfNotBlankValidator extends LengthValidator {
    public void initialize(LengthIfNotBlank parameters) {
        Map<String,Object> elements = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        elements.put("message", parameters.message());
        elements.put("payload", parameters.payload());
        elements.put("groups", parameters.groups());
        elements.put("min", parameters.min());
        elements.put("max", parameters.max());

        AnnotationDescriptor<Length> descriptor = AnnotationDescriptor.getInstance(Length.class, elements);
        Length length = AnnotationFactory.create(descriptor);
        super.initialize(length);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return StringUtils.isBlank(value) || super.isValid(value, constraintValidatorContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since annotation types cannot be inherited, you should override `initialize()` and pass an actual instance of type `Length` to `super.initialize()`.

Note that you cannot create an instance of annotation type directly, therefore you have to use something like [`AnnotationFactory`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/util/annotationfactory/AnnotationFactory.html).

Also I'm not sure that compiler would allow you to do it due to type safety constraints. If it doesn't, use composition instead of inheritance (i.e. create a field of type `LengthValidator`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not bother with that: Hibernate's `LengthValidator` is really simple and whatever you do, you will end up with more code that if you had just reimplemented the code yourself like this:

```
public class LengthIfNotBlankValidator implements ConstraintValidator<LengthIfNotBlank, String> {
    private int min;
    private int max;

    public void initialize(LengthIfNotBlank parameters) {
        min = parameters.min();
        max = parameters.max();
        validateParameters();
    }

    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if ( StringUtils.isBlank(value) ) {
            return true;
        }
        int length = value.length();
        return length >= min && length <= max;
    }

    private void validateParameters() {
        if ( min < 0 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "The min parameter cannot be negative." );
        }
        if ( max < 0 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "The max parameter cannot be negative." );
        }
        if ( max < min ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "The max cannot be less than the min." );
        }
    }
}
```

(This is just Hibernate's code adapted for your particular case).

Also, I don't think it would be possible to extend `LengthValidator` while implementing `ConstraintValidator<LengthIfNotBlank, String>`, which is mandatory for your validator.

Notice however that if you want to re-use unparameterized validators (or validators with constant parameters), you could simply annotate your validator with the re-used one (and maybe add `@ReportAsSingleViolation`)

Comment: I agree but I am not sure using reflection to avoid it is really better when the duplicated code is so simple. The reflection code is probably more difficult to understand and maintain…

Comment: +1 Really surprised to see that this answer which is >6 years old and on a question with 6K views didn't have a single upvote, it's a much simpler and better approach. Just because something is possible doesn't mean it *should* be done.